# Compilation error "has some invalid arguments" while calling method

Tags: c#, web-services

I am writing a webservice in c# where I deserialize object and save in DB using Entity Frame work. I am calling method GetFormData(refNo, form6a, ref form6aEntity, ref form6aDocs), where form6a is deserialized object and from6a entity is Entity framework generated class.This metod just maps the data from form6 object to form6aEntity object.

```
   if (new ECI.Handler.Form6aHandler().GetFormData(refNo, form6a, ref form6aEntity, ref form6aDocs))
                {
                  //  stateCode = form6aEntity.ST_CODE;
                  //  acNo = Convert.ToInt32(form6aEntity.AC_NO);
                    stateCode = form6aEntity.ST_CODE;
                    dbIps = new DBO().GetDbMap(stateCode);

                    foreach (string dbip in dbIps.Keys)
                    {
                        fornDbIp = dbip;
                    }
                    foreach (string aip in dbIps.Values)
                    {
                        attachmentDbIP = aip;
                    }
                    connectionString.Add("Forms", string.Format(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["NERMSConnString"].ToString(), fornDbIp, "All"));
                    connectionString.Add("Attachments", string.Format(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["NERMS_AttachmentConnString"].ToString(), attachmentDbIP, "All"));
                    formSaveStatus = new DBO().UpdateForm6A(form6aEntity, form6aDocs, connectionString);
                }
            }
```

Method definition looks like

```
public bool GetFormData(string formRefNo, Form6A formData, ref DBMLs.Form6a formEntity, ref ECI.DBMLs.Form6a_attachment formDocs)
    {
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            formDocs.AC_NO = Convert.ToInt32(formData.header.constituency_no);

            formData.attachment.applicant_passport = formData.attachment.applicant_passport.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", string.Empty);
            formDocs.applicant_passport = Convert.FromBase64String(formData.attachment.applicant_passport);

            formData.attachment.applicant_photo = formData.attachment.applicant_photo.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", string.Empty);
            formDocs.applicant_photo = Convert.FromBase64String(formData.attachment.applicant_photo);
            formDocs.REF_NO = formRefNo;
            formDocs.ST_CODE = formData.header.state_code;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.absent.since))
            formEntity.ABSENT_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.absent.since, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.ABSENT_DATE = formData.absent.since.ToNullable<DateTime>();
            formEntity.ABSENT_REASON = formData.absent.reason;
            formEntity.AC_NO = Convert.ToInt32(formData.header.constituency_no);


            formEntity.APPLICANT_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.declaration.applicant_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.APPLICANT_DATE = formData.declaration.applicant_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();
            formEntity.APPLICANT_PLACE = formData.declaration.applicant_place;
            formEntity.BIRTH_DISRTICT = formData.elector.birth_district;
            formEntity.BIRTH_PLACE = formData.elector.birth_place;
            formEntity.BIRTH_STATE = formData.elector.birth_state;
            formEntity.BIRTH_VILLAGE = formData.elector.birth_village;
            formEntity.DISTRICT_CODE = Convert.ToInt32(formData.address.district);

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.elector.dob))
            formEntity.DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.elector.dob, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(formData.elector.dob);
            formEntity.EMAIL_ID = formData.declaration.email_id;
            formEntity.FNAME_EN = formData.elector.name;
            formEntity.FNAME_V1 = formData.elector.name_v;
            formEntity.GENDER = formData.elector.gender;
            formEntity.HOUSE_NO = formData.address.house_no;
            formEntity.LNAME_EN = formData.elector.lname;
            formEntity.LNAME_V1 = formData.elector.lname_v;
            formEntity.MNAME_EN = formData.elector.mname;
            formEntity.MNAME_V1 = formData.elector.mname_v;
            formEntity.MOBILE_NO = formData.declaration.mobile_no;
            formEntity.O_ADDRESS_ABROAD = formData.abroad_add.official;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.passport.expiry_date))
            formEntity.PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.passport.expiry_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DATE = formData.passport.expiry_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.passport.issue_date))
            formEntity.PASSPORT_ISSUE_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.passport.issue_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.PASSPORT_ISSUE_DATE = formData.passport.issue_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();
            formEntity.PASSPORT_ISSUE_PLACE = formData.passport.issue_place;
            formEntity.PASSPORT_NO = formData.passport.no;
            formEntity.PIN_CODE = Convert.ToDecimal(formData.address.pincode);
            formEntity.POST_OFFICE = formData.address.postoffice;
            formEntity.PREV_AC_NAME = formData.prev_epic.constituency;
            //formEntity.PREV_EPIC_EXISTS = Convert.ToBoolean(formData.prev_epic.exists);

            formEntity.PREV_EPIC_EXISTS = formData.prev_epic.exists == "1" ? true : false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.prev_epic.issue_date))
            formEntity.PREV_EPIC_ISSUE_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.prev_epic.issue_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

           // formEntity.PREV_EPIC_ISSUE_DATE = formData.prev_epic.issue_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();
            formEntity.PREV_EPIC_NO = formData.prev_epic.no;
            formEntity.PREV_PLACE = formData.prev_epic.place;
            formEntity.PREV_STATE = formData.prev_epic.state;
            formEntity.R_ADDRESS_ABROAD = formData.abroad_add.residential;
            formEntity.REF_NO = formRefNo;
            formEntity.RLN_FNAME_EN = formData.relative.name;
            formEntity.RLN_FNAME_V1 = formData.relative.name_v;
            formEntity.RLN_LNAME_EN = formData.relative.lname;
            formEntity.RLN_LNAME_V1 = formData.relative.lname_v;
            formEntity.RLN_MNAME_EN = formData.relative.mname;
            formEntity.RLN_MNAME_V1 = formData.relative.mname_v;
            formEntity.RLN_TYPE = formData.relative.type;
            formEntity.ST_CODE = formData.header.state_code;
            formEntity.STREET_AREA = formData.address.street;
            formEntity.TEHSIL = formData.address.tehsil;
            formEntity.VILLAGE = formData.address.town;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.visa.expiry_date))
            formEntity.VISA_EXPIRY_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.visa.expiry_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            //formEntity.VISA_EXPIRY_DATE = formData.visa.expiry_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formData.visa.issue_date))
            formEntity.VISA_ISSUE_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.visa.issue_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            //formEntity.VISA_ISSUE_DATE = formData.visa.issue_date.ToNullable<DateTime>();
            formEntity.VISA_ISSUE_PLACE = formData.visa.issue_place;
            formEntity.VISA_ISSUING_AUTHORITY = formData.visa.issuing_authority;
            formEntity.VISA_NO = formData.visa.no;
            formEntity.VISA_TYPE = formData.visa.type;

            formEntity.FORM_SUBMISSION_DATE = DateTime.ParseExact(formData.declaration.applicant_date, "dd-mm-yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            status = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            status = false;                
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

When I compile, I get following error:

**Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'ECI.Handler.Form6aHandler.GetFormData(string, ECI.Forms.Form6a.Form6A, ref ECI.DBMLs.Form6a, ref ECI.DBMLs.Form6a_attachment)' has some invalid arguments**
[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfAZi.png)

Arguments Form6a:

```
public class Form6A
{
    public Form6A() {
        this.header = new Header();
        this.elector = new Elector();
        this.relative = new Relative();
        this.address = new Address();
        this.passport = new Passport();
        this.visa = new Visa();
        this.absent = new Absent();
        this.abroad_add = new AbroadAdd();
        this.prev_epic = new PrevEpic();
        this.declaration = new Declaration();
        this.attachment = new Attachment();
    }

    public Header header { get; set; }
    public Elector elector { get; set; }
    public Relative relative { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public Passport passport { get; set; }
    public Visa visa { get; set; }
    public Absent absent { get; set; }
    public AbroadAdd abroad_add { get; set; }
    public PrevEpic prev_epic { get; set; }
    public Declaration declaration { get; set; }
    public Attachment attachment { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.Append(this.header.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.elector.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.relative.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.address.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.passport.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.visa.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.absent.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.abroad_add.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.prev_epic.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.declaration.ToString() + ",");
        s.Append(this.attachment.ToString());
        return s.ToString();
    }
}
```

Form Entity

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Form6a")]
public partial class Form6a : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private string _REF_NO;

    private string _ST_CODE;

    private int _AC_NO;

    private System.Nullable<int> _PART_NO;

    private string _FNAME_EN;

    private string _FNAME_V1;

    private string _FNAME_V2;

    private string _FNAME_V3;

    private string _FNAME_V4;

    private string _MNAME_EN;

    private string _MNAME_V1;

    private string _MNAME_V2;

    private string _MNAME_V3;

    private string _MNAME_V4;

    private string _LNAME_EN;

    private string _LNAME_V1;

    private string _LNAME_V2;

    private string _LNAME_V3;

    private string _LNAME_V4;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _DOB;

    private string _GENDER;

    private string _BIRTH_PLACE;

    private string _BIRTH_VILLAGE;

    private string _BIRTH_DISRTICT;

    private string _BIRTH_STATE;

    private string _RLN_TYPE;

    private string _RLN_FNAME_EN;

    private string _RLN_FNAME_V1;

    private string _RLN_FNAME_V2;

    private string _RLN_FNAME_V3;

    private string _RLN_FNAME_V4;

    private string _RLN_MNAME_EN;

    private string _RLN_MNAME_V1;

    private string _RLN_MNAME_V2;

    private string _RLN_MNAME_V3;

    private string _RLN_MNAME_V4;

    private string _RLN_LNAME_EN;

    private string _RLN_LNAME_V1;

    private string _RLN_LNAME_V2;

    private string _RLN_LNAME_V3;

    private string _RLN_LNAME_V4;

    private string _SECTION_NO;

    private string _HOUSE_NO;

    private string _STREET_AREA;

    private string _VILLAGE;

    private string _POST_OFFICE;

    private System.Nullable<decimal> _PIN_CODE;

    private string _TEHSIL;

    private System.Nullable<int> _DISTRICT_CODE;

    private System.Nullable<bool> _PREV_EPIC_EXISTS;

    private string _PREV_EPIC_NO;

    private string _PREV_STATE;

    private string _PREV_AC_NAME;

    private string _PREV_PLACE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _PREV_EPIC_ISSUE_DATE;

    private string _APPLICANT_PLACE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _APPLICANT_DATE;

    private string _MOBILE_NO;

    private string _EMAIL_ID;

    private string _PASSPORT_NO;

    private string _PASSPORT_ISSUE_PLACE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _PASSPORT_ISSUE_DATE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _PASSPORT_EXPIRY_DATE;

    private string _VISA_NO;

    private string _VISA_TYPE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _VISA_ISSUE_DATE;

    private string _VISA_ISSUE_PLACE;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _VISA_EXPIRY_DATE;

    private string _VISA_ISSUING_AUTHORITY;

    private string _ABSENT_REASON;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _ABSENT_DATE;

    private string _R_ADDRESS_ABROAD;

    private string _O_ADDRESS_ABROAD;

    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> _FORM_SUBMISSION_DATE;

    private System.Nullable<bool> _IS_OFFLINE;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _APPLICANT_PHOTO;

    private System.Nullable<bool> _IS_SUBMITTED_TO_STATE;

    private System.Nullable<int> _RETRIAL_COUNT;

    private string _HOUSE_NO_V1;}
```

Form6Docs

```
public partial class Form6_attachment : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private long _ID;

    private string _REF_NO;

    private string _ST_CODE;

    private int _AC_NO;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _applicant_photo;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _dob_proof;

    private System.Data.Linq.Binary _residence_proof;}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] or at least enough code to actually see what's going on.

Comment: Well, your compiler says the arguments are invalid and you still haven't shown us what the arguments **are**.

Comment: I have elaborated the arguments.